# Load Bootstrap Modal content only when it has been opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap Modal to load lightboxes with some resource-heavy content.

But the content is loaded immediately with the page. And since there's several lightboxes it slows the page down significantly.

I want the content to load only when the modal button is clicked. But I don't want to call the modal code from a separate page, since that would complicate everything.

**Is there some way to use JS or AJAX to load the modal content only when the modal box opens?**

Somehow trigger it to load when the button is clicked and then turn the content off, when the box is closed.

Also bear in mind that I don't know almost anything about JS or AJAX.

--EDIT: It would be great if the same solution could be applied to tabbed content--

The code I'm using:

```
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
<iframe width='100%' height='368' src='#' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use the modal shown event to trigger an AJAX call to load your data. $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  AJAX_CALL_HERE
})

Comment: And how do I do that without loading the data from an external page? Since that would be a nightmare to set up for every individual lightbox I have.

I've Googled and the only thing I found gets data from an external page like here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load